# MS Access - Use VBA to automatically select yes for "access was unable to append all the data" error message

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using MS access where I click a button and it will upload a large number of files to my database. I want the user to be able to click the button and then minimise the application and when they come back all files are uploaded. However for a few of the files I get the error message "access was unable to append all the data to the table". This needs a user input and will not continue unless yes or no is selected.

For all these I always select yes, as I have a validation piece after this steps that will point out any issues.

Is there a way using VBA to build this yes selection into my code?

I already have the following in my code:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings = False
DoCmd.RunSQL ...
DoCmd.SetWarnings = True
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I use to execute sql, it returns the number of records effected by the SQL statement. It uses the 'On Error Resume Next' to handle any errors raised (not the best of coding practices).  The function returns a 0 - it failed, if more then that's the number of recs effected by the SQL statement.

```
Function execSQL(vSQL) As Long
On Error Resume Next

    Dim dbF As DAO.Database
    Dim lngRecs As Long
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Set dbF = CurrentDb
    dbF.Execute vSQL
    lngRecs = dbF.RecordsAffected
    execSQL = lngRecs
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
    dbF.Close
    Set dbF = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Failing that, it may be better to use dao to execute the sql instead and then you can error trap properly on that and move on to the next record.

Comment: Don't need SetWarnings with Execute method since Execute does not raise warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim strSql As String, fileName As String
    On Error GoTo Err_MySub
    'loop thru all files
        strSql = "...'" & fileName & "' ...."
        CurrentDb.Execute strSql
    'end of loop
    Exit Sub
Err_MySub:
    Debug.Print fileName & " gives this error:" & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Press Ctrl-G to show the debug window. Maybe you should do something more clever in the error handler.

Answer (score 1):

Action queries should be run using the `Execute()` method. No warnings of any kind are raised.

No parameters:

```
Currentdb().QueryDefs("QueryName").Execute dbFailOnError
```

With parameters:

```
With Currentdb().QueryDefs("QueryName")
    .Parameters("ParameterName").Value = ParameterValue
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```

The `dbFailOnError` option will generate a run-time error if the query fails for whatever reason, so make sure your method handles errors. Lastly, if you need to see the records affected, check the `RecordsAffected` property of the query.